# Guide for Building Audio Units in Xcode 5 on OSX 10.9

Tags: xcode, audio, core-audio, audiounit

I started reading the apple developer documentation for audio units [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/AudioUnitProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html), but I realized that the docs are very outdated and there appears to be no audio unit template available in xcode 5. I looked for quite some time yesterday and today for an up-to-date guide on building audio units, but to no avail. If anyone has a guide for building audio units in xcode 5 on OSX 10.9 I would be eternally grateful. Even better, if someone knows how to get the old audio unit templates into xcode 5, that would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The best resource I've found is [Adamson and Avila's book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321636848).

Highly recommended. You may need to tweak the code a bit to work in Xcode 5 but it shouldn't be too much work.